# Why can't I get data from many-to-many relationship in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am new to Entity Framework and I've been trying all day to work around this error. I've created a Code First Entity Data Model for my MVC application.

In my model I have a table USERS, a table PROPERTIES and a many to many relationship between them. The relationship is in a table RESTRICTIONS where I only have two foreign keys: ID_USER and ID_PROP.

My modeling:

```
public virtual DbSet<PROPERTIES> PROPERTIES{ get; set; }

public virtual DbSet<USERS> USERS { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    ...
    modelBuilder.Entity<USERS>()
            .HasMany(e => e.PROPERTIES
            .WithMany(e => e.USERS)
            .Map(m => 
    m.ToTable("RESTRICTIONS").MapLeftKey("ID_USER").MapRightKey("ID_PROP"));
    ...
}
```

In PROPERTIES.cs:

```
public partial class PROPERTIES
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", 
    "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public PROPERTIES()
    {
        USERS = new HashSet<USERS>();

    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public short ID_PROP { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string NAME { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", 
    "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<USERS> USERS { get; set; }


}
```

In USERS.cs:

```
public partial class USERS
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", 
    "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public USERS()
    {
        PROPERTIES= new HashSet<PROPERTIES>();            
    }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public short ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string USERNAME { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string PASSWORD { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", 
    "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<PROPERTIES> PROPERTIES{ get; set; }

}
```

My problem is when I'm trying to access the list of properties corresponding to a specific user. I'm doing this in a function in my controller like this:

```
MyDBModel db = new MyDBModel();
USERS user1 = db.USERS.Find(id1);
ICollection<PROPERTIES> properties1 = user1.PROPERTIES;
```

But the app crashes. I put a breakpoint after retrieving user1 from the database and I've noticed that in front of the field PROPERTIES for user1 I have the following error

> '((System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.USERS_55FDBB1984D5B66D96801B0B7439AD715048C52F9A7D1DFF17B61D029DE77280)user1).PROPERTIES' threw an exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException'

When I expand PROPERTIES I see some errors here:

[image]

Why does this happen?

Comment: What is the exception message?

Comment: {"ORA-00942: table or view does not exist"} System.Exception

Comment: That's strange and normally does not happen. The mappings shown look ok. Did you create the database from the EF model or it was created separately? And there is table named `RESTRICTIONS`? Can you log the SQL EF is executing?

Comment: The database was created separately, before creating the model. The model was created based on the database. Yes, there is a table named RESTRICTIONS. I'm sorry, I don't understand the last question

Comment: Insert `db.Log = s => Debug.Print(s);` before `ICollection<PROPERTIES> properties1 = user1.PROPERTIES;` line and take a look at the debug output when execute it - you should be able the see the SQL command text that EF executes to retrieve `user1.PROPERTIES`. Another way is `var sql = db.USERS.Include(u => u.PROPERTIES).ToString();` and examine the `sql` variable in debugger.